# Very long 'Unique ID' in Windows 2008 DHCP Server Leases - why? What is the device?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, dhcp

I notice on one Windows 2008 R2 DHCP server the device with the first IP in the range has a strange looking Unique ID of the format

> 636333652e356639322e326262332d445c458e41258s23148914e1554654566661636531

And the DNS name HP.domain.local

See screenshot.  Does anyone know what this is and why it doesn't show a standard MAC for the unique ID?
[image: DHCP Screenshot]

Comment: Recent versions of Ubuntu also generate long IDs, but in a different format. 
 https://serverfault.com/questions/1056906/fresh-ubuntu-20-server-getting-wrong-dhcp-address

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Split the string in pairs and convert hex to ascii, you will get `cc3e.5f92.2bb3-Vlan-interface1`, it is most probably one of your HP switches registering.

Comment: Seeing this, I was inspired to write a little online one on my site: http://jemnetworks.com/unique-id