# Fresh Ubuntu 20 server getting wrong DHCP address

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, dhcp, ipv4, ubuntu-20.04

I need to setup a new Linux server on VirtualBox, I'm using Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS and in Virtualbox my network adapter is set to bridge adapter with promiscuous mode on "allow all"

First of all I permanently disabled IPV6 using [this tutorial](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-disable-ipv6-address-on-ubuntu-20-04-lts-focal-fossa)

The server is set to get a DHCP address from a Windows Server 2012 DCHP with Active directory, but I´m setting up an address reservation using the VM MAC address (just to keep a centralized point where i change all my network leases)

This same configuration is working perfectly on an old Ubuntu Server 18 instalation

But on the Ubuntu 20 Server wont get the correct address, seeing on the DHCP panel the MAC address seems to be "e2343f3e00020000ab111033439cdd1678e3" instead of the expected "08002758510A"

[image: DHCP Panel]

I know i can setup a fixed IP on Ubuntu (i have done it and it works), but as I said, I need to keep a centralized point in the DHPCP Server, from where i can reorganize all the address in case of need

Does anyone knows why is happening this and how can i fix it?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just found that Ubuntu 18+ uses a different approach when getting the DHCP address, for those with the same problem you only need to change your netplan configuration and set dhcp-identifier to mac:

```
network:
    renderer: networkd
    version: 2
    ethernets:
        {nicdevicename}:
            dhcp4: true
            dhcp-identifier: mac
```

https://superuser.com/questions/1338510/wrong-ip-address-from-dhcp-client-on-ubuntu-18-04

Answer (score 0):

That is clearly not a MAC address being shown in Windows Server 2012. Perhaps the header says [Client Unique Identifier](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-2000-server/cc977614(v=technet.10))? Get the MAC address from the Ubuntu server (`cat /sys/class/net/*/address` will show the MAC addresses for all the NICs) or from VirtualBox and put it into your Windows Server 2012 static DHCP config.

Comment: Your answer gave me a hint and i found the real solution, I'm posting it below so anyone can find it again.. Thanks!!